# cal heatmap web layout

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, heatmap

[image]

This is my current layout.
I centered the heatmap, but the information it displays will run away. How can I modify it?

```
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height: 200px; background-color:teal;">    
    <div id="cal-heatmap" align="center"></div>
</div>
<script>
d3.csv(json_url, function (error, result) {
  
    var cal = new CalHeatMap();    
    cal.init({
        itemSelector: "#cal-heatmap",
        itemName: ["μm<br/>", "μm<br/>"],
        displayLegend: false,
        cellSize: 20,
        tooltip: true,
        data: result,
        start: new Date(2020, 4),
        domain: "day",          // Group data by month
        subDomain: "hour",          // Split each month by days
        legend: [-1, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
        subDomainTextFormat: "%-H",
        browsing: true,
        nextSelector: "#domain-highlight-next-selector",
        previousSelector: "#domain-highlight-previous-selector",
        range: 10, 
 
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you help us by recreating that example using this? https://codesandbox.io/s/ and share the link.

Comment: Here.http://plnkr.co/edit/MXQjwe2EkXz0rxGK?preview